# SQLBindParameter returns -1

Tags: c++, parameters, odbc

My code is as follows:

```
std::wstring ownerName = table->GetTableOwner();
SQLWCHAR *owner_name = new SQLWCHAR[ownerNameLen + 2];
int ownerNameLen = ownerName.length();
SQLLEN cbOwnerName = ownerNameLen == 0 ? SQL_NULL_DATA : SQL_NTS;
ret = SQLBindParameter( stmt_tableProp, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WCHAR, ownerNameLen, 0, owner_name, 0, &cbOwnerName );
```

The call to SQLBindParameter succeeds when the owner_name contains an actual data. However if the owner_name is '' the call fails. And the error message I am getting is "HY104 - Invalid precision or scale value".

According to MSDN it looks like the value for the size should be the size of the column and not the size of the actual parameter. Is this correct? Or I should pass 0 as the length of the binding value?

Also, there is [this page](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?747830-how-to-insert-a-null-value-using-SQLBindParameter) which uses different values.

Could someone please shed some light?

Comment: From the page, you linked: _the length values have to be at least 1 (don't ask me why) otherwise you get an adequate error message._ It seems the answer is right there?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter in SqlBindParameter where you are passing ownerNameLen value should contain column size, not variable size. This is what required by column data type you are working with(SQL_WCHAR) according to the docs.  Below is a link to the docs. Look for the "ColumnSize Argument" and see for yourself.

[SqlBindParameter doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function)